# Could not deploy pub/sub function via firebase deploy

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm currently working on deploying a simple pub/sub function to Firebase function.

Here are the steps that I have done:

- Create a topic name `subscription-listener` in Cloud Pub/Sub
- Enable Cloud Run (I have not created any service yet)
- Initialize Firebase functions project via `firebase init`
- Enable billing in my Cloud project

When I tried to deploy via `firebase deploy`, it shows error like below:

```
⚠  functions: HTTP Error: 400, Could not create Cloud Run service helloworld. spec.template.spec.containers.resources.limits.cpu: Invalid value specified for cpu. For the specified value, maxScale may not exceed 10.
Consider running your workload in a region with greater capacity, decreasing your requested cpu-per-instance, or requesting an increase in quota for this region if you are seeing sustained usage near this limit, see https://cloud.google.com/run/quotas. Your project may gain access to further scaling by adding billing information to your account.
⚠  functions: failed to create function projects/my-project/locations/us-central1/functions/helloWorld
Failed to create function projects/my-project/locations/us-central1/functions/helloWorld
```

Are there any steps that I was missing?

Below is my code in firebase function:

```
import { logger, pubsub } from "firebase-functions/v2";

exports.helloWorld = pubsub.onMessagePublished(
  "subscription-listener",
  (event) => {
    logger.log("Event data: ", event.data.message);
  }
);
```

Comment: Enable billing for that project. That is what the error is telling you to do.

Comment: I have enabled billing for the project but the issue still remains.